# How to call multiple different methods simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I have some different methods that each import products from different sites.
If I execute these sequentially the entire process takes a lot of time, particularly when 1 method is running on a site that is less responsive.

I'd rather run them simultaneously.

This is what I have so far with 1 example method:

```
Public Class feedParameters

Private _productIdPrefix As String
Private _publishersite As String
Private _feedURL As String

Public Property productIdPrefix() As String
    Get
        Return _productIdPrefix
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _productIdPrefix = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property publishersite() As String
    Get
        Return _publishersite
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _publishersite = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property feedURL() As String
    Get
        Return _feedURL
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _feedURL = value
    End Set
End Property


End Class




Dim fpm As New feedParameters
fpm.publishersite = "mypublisher.nl"
fpm.feedURL = "http://www.domain.com/test.xml"
fpm.productIdPrefix = "10"

Protected Sub ImportProductsPublisherA(ByVal productIdPrefix As String, ByVal publishersite As String, ByVal feedURL As String)

End Sub
```

I tried this:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsPublisherA()), fpm)
```

Then I get 3 errors that I have not specified arguments for the 3 parameters: productIdPrefix, publishersite and feedURL

I also tried:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsPublisherA), fpm)
```

I get this error:
Method 'Protected Sub ImportProductsPublisherA(productIdPrefix As String, publishersite As String, feedURL As String)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub WaitCallback(state As Object)'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this WinForms or asp.net?

If winforms create a background worker for each function and start all of them, they will work independently in a separate thread.

If asp.net you want to look at using `System.Threading.ThreadPool` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsSiteA))

System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsSiteB))

System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsSiteC))

System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsSiteD))
```

If you functions take any parameters you can pass them like this:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ImportProductsSiteA), parameter-here)
```

Comment: It's asp.net. And I looked at the link you provided, but how would I call my 4 methods using that technique? I don't understand the logic yet :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this works when passing 1 parameter to a function, but what if I want to pass more parameters? In my case 2 strings and 1 integer?

Comment: Create a new class with those parameters and pass that in.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but that didn't work for me. I updated my initial post...could you have another look?

Comment: You need to change your functions to accept the the new object as the parameter - currently it's still expecting 2 strings and an integer, not your new `feedParemeters` class.

Comment: Ok, that was kinda stupid :) I thought earlier the class propertynames just would have to match the parameter names. It now works, thanks!

Comment: I did what you said, and started about 5 threads, but now my site is  either only executing 1 method out of the 5 called or stopping the IIS application pool all together. 
In case the app pool is NOT stopped, there's nothing in my ISS file, otherwise my IIS log is just mentioning this line 20x:
2013-05-06 22:07:11 192.168.0.10 GET /files/productfeed.xml - 80 - 192.168.0.10 - - 200 0 0 1062
which is the feed that is not being imported
I tried setting the Maximum Worker Processes property of the application pool to 5.
What is happening?

Comment: One or more of your functions are failing, try testing them without running them asynchronously in your dev environment to see if there are any errors. Also read up on thread safety, if your functions make any cross thread calls they will fail.

Comment: The individual functions are not failing when I run them synchronously. The only functions I'm calling from within the functions to be called asynchronously is this one: 
Protected Function ReplaceProductIdLettersWithNumbers(ByVal currentProductId As String) As String
and an insert method on a tableadapter.

Are those considered cross thread calls?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess and say that calling that function isn't thread safe. Break it down, use your dev environment (not iis server) and test test test. If you are wanting to use asynchronous calls then it's imperative that you understand thread safety. Otherwise you're going to find this fairly challenging. I'd maybe suggest starting a test project and play around with threading, read up about how to access resources from different threads. It can seem a little daunting at first but once you've got you head around the basics it isn't too difficult.

Comment: Perfect! And if a multithreaded function returns a value, how would I get that value?

Comment: You can't return a value as is the nature with threads, but there are several other options, a field in a class, events, delegates. Some examples here, they're in c# but just use a converter. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/c43c0cce-491a-4ddb-9012-69929fab8e5e

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Foo
{
   public class Bar
   {
      public void ImportProductsSiteA() { }
      public void ImportProductsSiteB() { }
      public void ImportProductsSiteC() { }
      public void ImportProductsSiteD() { }

      public void Execute()
      {
         var a = Task.Factory.StartNew(ImportProductsSiteA);
         var b = Task.Factory.StartNew(ImportProductsSiteB);
         var c = Task.Factory.StartNew(ImportProductsSiteC);
         var d = Task.Factory.StartNew(ImportProductsSiteD);
         Task.WaitAll(a, b, c, d);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I now have:
Dim a As System.Threading.Tasks.Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ImportProductsSiteA)

But then I get the error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'StartNew' can be called with these arguments:'Public Function StartNew(Of TResult)(function As System.Func(Of TResult)) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of TResult)': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments.Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.'Public Function StartNew(action As System.Action) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task': Expression does not produce a value.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's the C# version. I'm not sure what the syntax would be for VB.